# Why does vpc comes out from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2'?

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

Please understand that I'm a newbie, just starting to learn the CDK and AWS networks.

While configuring a VPC using the CDK, I came across the code below.

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class NetworkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  readonly vpc: ec2.Vpc;
  
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
  }
}
```

Why is it used as if VPC is dependent on `aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2`? Is there any relationship between EC2 and VPC?

I was expecting the VPC to be in something like 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-network'.

Comment: VPC management is part of the EC2 services and API.  I suspect it's like this because VPCs have been available for a very long time, and were traditionally managed there.  AWS offers dozens of more services than they used to, even a decade ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only AWS can give a *definitive* answer here, but @Brad already points out some reasons along the lines of "that's how the system evolved over time" in the comments.

Maybe for some [historical context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Amazon_Web_Services):

- EC2 was launched in 2006 and had a very basic for of networking now called EC2 classic, which has been largely discontinued
- VPC was [launched in 2009](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-virtual-private-cloud-vpc/) back when almost any compute service was *really* closely coupled to EC2 instances

Back then, there weren't many other services around that could really integrate into a private network (S3, SQS, ...) or those that existed (ELB) were tightly integrated with EC2 again so it was convenient to manage them in a single API.

The "Zoo" of services that we have now took a while to develop. Over time newer APIs got their own service-scope in the API.

AWS has historically taken the idea of "an API is a promise" very seriously so they don't break old APIs (with *very* few exceptions). This means we're sort of stuck with that state of things. It's one of those things that don't really matter in practice but seem quirky when you first learn about them.

CloudFormation (the service underlying the CDK) also respects the Namespacing of the underlying AWS API for the most part, and so does the CDK. In CDK v1 there used to be separate packages you'd need to install for each service you were using. That part is now a lot easier, but the service separation remains.

If they could go back in time, that's maybe one of the things that would be organized a bit differently.